Android app crash with "No view found for id" #0x7f0a010c
When I run my APK in Android Studio, the app crashes and does not launch. It shows:
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.statussaverapp/com.example.statussaverapp.views.activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.statussaverapp/.views.activities.MainActivity } 

Logcat shows:
java.lang.IligalArgumentException : No view found for id 0x7f0a010c (com.example.statussaverapp: id/fragment _container) for fragment FragmentStatus{e1ff00c}


Post the code where the exception is happening.  The file and line number should be in the logs as well.

Please share your code I think so there is something wrong in your XML file of fragment class or main activity
